# The Delete code doesnt work after it updates a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I send data to the procedure which contains the `ResStatus as C` it updates the **ResMaster's ResStatus as X**
After it updates the column, I want to delete a record from 2 tables they are- Folio,ResRoomAllocation.

I have done the coding but it doesn't work it only updates the `ResStatus as X`

What's wrong with my code?I'm new to MSSQL

```
IF EXISTS(Select TOP (1) * From ResMaster Where VoucherNo = @BookingId AND ResStatus ='C')
    BEGIN
        Update ResMaster
        Set ResStatus = 'X'
        Where VoucherNo = @BookingId

        DECLARE @RemoveBookingId NVARCHAR = (Select ResNo from ResMaster where VoucherNo = @BookingId)

        DELETE FROM Folio WHERE ResNo = @RemoveBookingId
        DELETE FROM ResRoomAllocation  WHERE ResNo = @RemoveBookingId
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). You have `DECLARE @RemoveBookingId NVARCHAR`, which means `DECLARE @RemoveBookingId NVARCHAR(1)`. I doubt that `ResNo` is only 1 or 0 characters long.

Comment: The best practice is to make sure parameters and variables exactly match the referenced column data type and length to avoid surprises. Separately, there is no need for `TOP` in the `EXISTS` subquery. SQL Server will optimize the query properly without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what other problems you have in the code, but this is simply wrong:

```
  DECLARE @RemoveBookingId NVARCHAR = (Select ResNo from ResMaster where VoucherNo = @BookingId);
```

First, "id"s are often stored as numbers, especially when associated with something with a name like "ResNo" (presumably "no" implies number).

But let me assume that `ResNo` is a string.  Your declaration:

```
DECLARE @RemoveBookingId NVARCHAR;
```

declares a string with ONE character.  That usually breaks code.  You need a length -- preferably the correct on.  I tend to use `255` when I don't know the length:

```
DECLARE @RemoveBookingId NVARCHAR(255);
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the length of variable `@RemoveBookingId` :

```
DECLARE @RemoveBookingId NVARCHAR(255) -- default will be 1 character length
```

So, declare ti with proper length.

AND, you don't need to use `EXISTS`, add one more condition with `WHERE` clause  :

```
DECLARE @RemoveBookingId NVARCHAR(255) 

Update ResMaster
      Set ResStatus = 'X'
Where VoucherNo = @BookingId and ResStatus = 'C';

SELECT @RemoveBookingId = ResNo 
FROM ResMaster 
WHERE VoucherNo = @BookingId AND ResStatus = 'C';
```

Note : This will return error if query found multiple row. So, use top `(1)`.